# Shapely import and to_geojson()

Tags: python, geojson, shapely

I am attempting to convert a `shapely` `LineString` to GeoJSON.

According to the [Shapely documentation](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/shapely.to_geojson.html#shapely-to-geojson), there is a method called `shapely.to_geojson()` which should be able to do this.

However, when I try to call `shapely.to_geojson()`, I get the error `AttributeError: module 'shapely' has no attribute 'to_geojson'`. I'm also confused since the shapely documentation just shows to_geojson() being called by itself without being imported.

I was similarly unsuccessful in calling `linestring_object.to_geojson()`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your shapely version ?

With version 2.x

```
import shapely
shapely.__version__
'2.0.1'
from shapely.geometry import LineString, mapping
line = LineString([(2, 0), (2, 4), (3, 4)])
shapely.to_geojson(line)
{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[2.0,0.0],[2.0,4.0],[3.0,4.0]]}
mapping(line)
{'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': ((2.0, 0.0), (2.0, 4.0), (3.0, 4.0))}
```

With version 1.x

```
import shapely
shapely.__version__
'1.8.2'
from shapely.geometry import LineString, mapping
line = LineString([(2, 0), (2, 4), (3, 4)])
shapely.to_geojson(line)
Traceback (most recent call last):File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'shapely' has no attribute 'to_geojson'
mapping(line)
{'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': ((2.0, 0.0), (2.0, 4.0), (3.0, 4.0))}
```

Comment: That was it! Knew it was something easy. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

Here goes a simple conversion example

```
import geojson
import shapely.wkt

# sample linestring
linestring = shapely.wkt.loads("LINESTRING(0 0, 1 1, 2 2, 3 3, 4 4, 5 5, 6 6, 7 7, 8 8, 9 9, 10 10)")
# create a feature
feature = geojson.Feature(geometry=linestring, properties={"name": "line"})
# create a feature collection
feature_collection = geojson.FeatureCollection([feature])
# print the geojson
print(geojson.dumps(feature_collection, sort_keys=True))
```

Comment: Thank you! This will work, but I had really hoped to better understand why I wasn't able to make this work with shapely's built-in to_geojson() function.